# Linear transformation in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $e_1= \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $e_2= \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let

$y_1= \begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5
\end{bmatrix}
$

$y_2= \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
6
\end{bmatrix}
$

Let $\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$ be a linear transformation that maps e1 into y1 and e2 into y2.

Find the images of

$A= \begin{bmatrix}  
5\\
-3
\end{bmatrix}
$

$b= \begin{bmatrix}  
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
$

I am not sure how to this. I think there is a 2x2 matrix that you have to find that vies you the image of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that:
$$
\vec b = x\vec e_1 + y\vec e_2
$$
so by the linearity of the given transformation $T$, we know that:
$$
T(\vec b) = xT(\vec e_1) + yT(\vec e_2) = x\vec y_1 + y \vec y_2
$$

Comment: I think I get the hint but how would you find the image of A.Beause if you have a 2x1 matrix and 2x1 matrix it cant be combined.

Comment: Do the same thing as before, except with $x = 5$ and $y = -3$.

Comment: Oh ok yes it makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is a linear transformation that maps $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$
to $\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5
\end{bmatrix}
$, $L$ has a matrix representation $A$, such that $A \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5
\end{bmatrix}$. But this means that $\vec{a_1}^{\,}$ is just $\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5
\end{bmatrix}$.

The same reasoning can be applied to find the second column vector of $A$.

Once you have the matrix representation of $L$, you're good.